# docker compose file to create jenkins container and while executing i am getting this following error

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, devops

I am using docker compose file to create jenkins container and while executing i am getting the following error: `"ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', network must be a mapping, not a string"`

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "$pwd/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to match the Compose file you included.  But maybe the answer is just to delete all of the `networks:` blocks from the file.  If you do, Compose will create a network named `default` and attach the container(s) to it, and this is correct for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

As in David Maze's comment, there's no YAML key called "network" in the compose file you've provided. That file works fine for me.

However, I think Docker throws warnings using the singular rather than the plural, so I'd check your indentation for the networks block.